# Rails 5: permission for user to create record through permission table with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, pundit

In my app I have Permission table, which stores all the logic what User can do. **With Pundit I want to allow User to create new Campaign if Permission table allows.** User can access  Campaigns and create new, if Permission table contains this info:

- permitable_type: Sysmodule   *// another table where I store info on System sections, where Campaigns is one of*
- permitable_id: 2   *// means Campaigns from Sysmodule*
- level: 3   *// means User can edit something in Campaigns section*

So far I keep getting error *"Pundit::NotDefinedError", unable to find policy of nil*  policies/application_policy.rb is standart, no changes.
Obviously I am doing sothing wrong. How do I do this authorization correctly? Many thanks for any help! I am on Rails 5 + Pundit.

models/permission.rb

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  enum level: {owner: 1, view: 2, edit: 3}
end
```

models/user.rb

```
has_many :permissions
has_many :campaigns, through: :permissions, source: :permitable, source_type: 'Campaign' do
  def owner_of
  where('`permissions`.`level` & ? > 0', Permission::owner )
  end
end

has_many :sysmodules, through: :permissions, source: :permitable, source_type: 'Sysmodule' do
  def can_access
  where('`permissions`.`level` & ? > 1', Permission::can_access )
  end
end
```

controllers/campaigns_controller.rb

```
def new
  @campaign = Campaign.new
  authorize @campaign
end
```

policies/campaign_policy.rb

```
class CampaignPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
attr_reader :user, :campaign, :permission
  @user = user
  @permission = permission
end
def new?
  user.permission? ({level: 3, permitable_type: "Sysmodule", permitable_id: 2})
end
```

views/campaigns/index.html.erb

```
<% if policy(@campaign).new? %>
</li>
   <li><%= link_to "New campaign", new_campaign_path(@campaign) %></li>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Joining everything though a polymorphic relation on the `permissions` table is going to be a huge performance problem. Also calling class methods though `::` (`Permission::owner`) is not good style in Ruby as it looks like you are accessing a module constant.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is `Permission.levels[:owner]`. `Permission::owner` is actually equal to `Permission.where(level: :owner)`

Comment: @max What's your suggestion to be able to set permissions (View/Edit/Delete) for any object (e.g., Campaign) for any User? Let's assume, from 10 campaigns in database, User can View two, Edit two, is Owner of two, but cannot access four.

Comment: A basic role based access system might be a better alternative. https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

Comment: @max I checked Rolify before, however I did not get, how I will be able to allow User to have access on single record level (e.g. Campaign). Do you have any suggestion what should I change in this code to make Campaign policy work, please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing directly with what permissions a user should have try thinking of it what roles users can have in a system.

This makes it much easier to create authorization rules that map to real world problems.

Lets imagine an example where we have users and groups. The rules are as follows:

- groups can be created by any user
- the user that creates the group automatically becomes an admin
- groups are private
- only admins or members can view a group
- only an admin can modify a group

The models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify 
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  resourcify
end
```

The policy:

```
class GroupsPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.with_roles([:admin, :member], current_user)
    end
  end

  def show?
    user.has_role?([:member, :admin], record)
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def create?
    true # any user can create
  end

  def new? 
   create?
  end

  def update?
    user.has_role?(:admin, record)
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    update?
  end
end
```

The controller

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html

  before_action :autenticate!
  before_action :set_group!, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def index
    @groups = policy_scope(Group.all)
    respond_with(@groups)
  end

  def new
    @group = authorize( Group.new )
  end

  def create
    @group = authorize( Group.new(group_attributes) )
    if @group.save
      current_user.add_role(:member, @group)
      current_user.add_role(:admin, @group)
    end
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @group.update(group_params)
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  def destroy
    @group.destroy
    respond_with(@group)
  end

  private 
    def set_group!
       @group = authorize( Group.find(params[:id]) )
    end

    def group_params
       params.require(:group).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. I probably could use Rolify for few general roles I have in my app. However I need to allow to assign permissions for some objects on record level. Do you think it would be ok performance wise, if I leave Permissions table for that purpose and move everything else to roles? I mean, I could probably optimize Permissions table, e.g., permitable_type could be Enum. Probably I have to optimize some queries as well.